# Modificar el estilo de un conjunto de span tags mediante una función en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

En el html tengo ocho palabras con la etiqueta "span" dentro de un párrafo. En el .css defino el estilo del cursor:

```
span{
    cursor: grab;
}
```

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es de cambiar el estilo del cursor de todas las palabras con el tag de span nuevamente a default mediante la siguiente función que se llama con el onmouseover

```
stepThree = () => {
    if (two >= 1 && three <= 0) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].style.cursor = 'default';
    }
```

El problema es que sólo se modifica el estilo del span de la última posición en el array...

Comment: Agrega tu HTML por favor

Comment: Has intentado recorrer con un for lo que devuelve getElementsByTagName? Para que lo cambie uno por uno?

Comment: No tenía en claro cómo se estaba comportando el código. Si, con un for se hubiese podido resolver. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema que tienes es que efectivamente estás accediendo siempre al último elemento, la forma en la que estás accediendo al conjunto de elementos `span` se puede explicar así:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
const getElement = numbers[0, 1]; // Línea en la que accedes

console.log(getElement);
```

En la segunda línea *"Línea en la que accedes"* estás accediendo a la posición de un arreglo y Javascript ignora todos los números excepto el último, por lo que en el ejemplo siempre estás accediendo a la segunda posición del arreglo `numbers` lo cual es lo mismo que escribir

```
const getElement = numbers[1];
```

---

**¿Cómo hacer lo que necesitas?**

Para ello tienes que aplicar la misma transformación elemento a elemento del conjunto de tags `span` que encuentres, de la siguiente forma lo podrías hacer:

```js
function changeCursor() {
    [...document.getElementsByTagName('span')].forEach(element => {
        element.style.cursor = 'grab';
    })
}
```

```html
<p>
    <span>Texto 1</span>
    <span>Texto 2</span>
    <span>Texto 3</span>
    <span>Texto 4</span>
    <span>Texto 5</span>
</p>

<button onclick="changeCursor()">Cambiar cursor</button>
```

En este ejemplo primero convertimos una colección de elementos iterables `document.getElementsByTagName('span')` en un arreglo, eso lo hacemos gracias a la sintaxis del spread operator `...` e introducimos esos elementos en un arreglo, luego gracias a que tenemos un arreglo de elementos podemos utilizar un `forEach` sobre estos elementos y modificamos elemento a elemento cada propiedad, eso es lo que te faltaba, aplicar la propiedad a **cada uno de los elementos**.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Excelente respuesta!